# Cloned jQuery Obejects and CodeIgniter $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, caching

I'm having a problem with cloned objects and CodeIgniter. I need to show the cloned fields on the next page when form is submitted. There are some logic to save the cloned fields compatible with the most browsers? And sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get some data to the next page, using the session could be a solution.
CodeIgniter uses `flashdata` for storing temporary information in the session.

To set a value you can use:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

To read it again on the next request you use:

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

After the next request the variable is destroyed. More information can be found in the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Show us some code, perhaps we can provide a more accurate solution.

Comment: I heard about flashdata and I'm using it on this project, but... How can I put a complete cloned fieldset into a flashdata?

Comment: You would need to use an ajax request to send a cookie or as Robert suggested a session(flashdata)